# Overriding function and including async/await

Tags: .net, async-await

I have a class called `WebUtil` and in it is an abstract function called `GetWebpage()`. In one implementation of this function I use the `WebClient` class, in another I use the new `HttpClient` with its await/async functionality. Problem is the use of `HttpClient` requires the method to return `Task<>`, so I changed the abstract method definition. But now the function that uses the `WebClient` has to also return `Task<>`.

Is there a good way to handle this? Is there something I'm not familiar with?

Comment: [`WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194010.aspx)?

Comment: We are missing some context here as to why your're still using the WebClient and a non task-based version of it, but are you aware that a [Portable HttpClient is now available as RTM](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/05/29/portable-httpclient-is-now-available-as-rtm.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, Paulo. My discovery of the NuGet package for HttpClient is what got me here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return `Task<>` with the `WebClient` with `Task.FromResult`.

```
Task<string> GetWebPage(string url)
{
    var c = new WebClient();
    var html = c.DownloadString(url);
    return Task.FromResult(html);
}
```

Or, you can use `TaskCompleteSource<T>` convert events to task:

```
Task<string> GetWebPage(string url)
{
    var c = new WebClient();
    var tcs = new TaskCompleteSource<string>();
    c.DownloadStringCompleted += (o, e) => tcs.SetResult((string)e.Result);
    c.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: See Kirill's answer for exception handling.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to stick with one or the other. Personally, I would pick async and rework the override which uses WebClient to return a Task. You will get more bang for your buck in terms of functionality (see the code snippet for CancellationToken support, for example). This also happens to be a better design due the *non-blocking* nature of this method.

```
    public override Task<string> GetWebpage(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                tcs.SetCanceled();
            }
            else if (e.Error != null)
            {
                tcs.SetException(e.Error);
            }
            else 
            {
                tcs.SetResult(e.Result);
            }
        };

        client.DownloadStringAsync(this.Url);

        if (cancellationToken.CanBeCanceled)
        {
            cancellationToken.Register(client.CancelAsync);
        }

        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Stephen Cleary mentioned in a comment, `WebClient` does support `async` too, so you can just call one of the `-TaskAsync` methods.

But in general, it's okay to implement `async` interface using either `Task.FromResult()` (if the method is fast), or `Task.Run()` (if it's slow).

Comment: Regarding using Task.Run(...) to encapsulate a blocking call: I'm a bit of a nazi when it comes to that. Creating a task which may potentially spawn a new thread *just to have it blocked* waiting for the synchronous DownloadString method to return is a poor choice when there is a perfectly good (albeit old-fashioned) async api available.

Comment: Having said that, your other suggestion, which involves the -TaskAsync methods, is spot on.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy Yeah, you're right that that would be wasteful. I meant that you should use `Task.Run()` if you have long-running operation that doesn't have asynchronous alternative.